# Flutter: how can I use service when using riverpod provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

just start learning about riverpod and I want to use FlutterSecureStorage inside provider
the problem is I don't know if what I did is right or not

I want to create a service and implement some methods to help me use `FlutterSecureStorage` the use this service with Provider so I can access it from all the app

here's the code:

storage_service.dart

```
class StorageService {
  final _secureStorage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

  AndroidOptions _getAndroidOptions() => const AndroidOptions(
        encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
      );

  Future<void> writeSecureData(StorageItem newItem) async {
    await _secureStorage.write(
        key: newItem.key, value: newItem.value, aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
  }
...
  Future<List<StorageItem>> readAllSecureData() async {
    var allData = await _secureStorage.readAll(aOptions: _getAndroidOptions());
    List<StorageItem> list =
        allData.entries.map((e) => StorageItem(e.key, e.value)).toList();
    return list;
  }
...
}

final storageServiceProvider = Provider((ref) => StorageService());
```

Home Screen:

```
class HomeScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final storageService = ref.watch(storageServiceProvider);
    List<StorageItem> data = [];
    storageService.readAllSecureData().then((value) => data = value);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'HomeScreen',
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Key: ${data[index].key}'),
                      Text('Value: ${data[index].value}'),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final List<StorageItem> st =
                      await storageService.readAllSecureData();
                  debugPrint('button Pressed ${st.length}');
                  st.map(
                      (e) => debugPrint('Key: ${e.key} | Value: ${e.value}'));
                  final StorageItem newItem = StorageItem('sup', 'test');
                  storageService.writeSecureData(newItem);
                  // context.goNamed(AppRoutingConstans.loginScreenRouteName);
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                  minimumSize: const Size(50, 50),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 148.0),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Text(
                  'Go To Login Screen',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd rewrite StorageService as a AsyncNotifier<AllSecureData>  with state being that data you get from the secure storage. Then, the watch by your HomeScreen would give you progress/done/error status.

Comment: could you explain it more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave it the way it is. However, something needs to be done about this line:

```dart
storageService.readAllSecureData().then((value) => data = value);
```

Two options to choose from:

- use `FutureBuilder` or
- use `setState` within `then`:

```dart
storageService.readAllSecureData().then((value) {
  setState((){data = value;});
});
```

Next, you need to put it all in `initState`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  final storageService = ref.read(storageServiceProvider);
  storageService.readAllSecureData().then((value) {
    setState((){data = value;});
  });
}
```

and add the creation of the list to the fields of the `_HomeScreenState` class:

```dart
class _HomeScreenState extends ConsumerState<HomeScreen> {
  List<StorageItem> data = [];

...
```

---

Next, you need to think about the right architecture and *Single-responsibility principle*. Your interface should only display the already PREPARED information and nothing more. He must not know anything about the repository, about how to change the data already in place, and not have unnecessary ways to change the data.

Everything that a class can do must be passed as a dependency in the constructor, or (in our case, Riverpod) as `ref.watch(onlyNecessaryMethodsProvider)`.

Therefore, it would be *necessary to allocate all the logic* of reference to the storage, the conversion of existing data in a separate widget helper class. Usually it is called `PageController` or `PagePresenter`, which contains all the logic for working with this page and the methods that will be called during user interactions

---

**Update:**

Nowadays, with the advent of Riverpod 2.0, you should be using exactly `(Async)NotifierProvider` to build your states. You can write all dependencies in it directly in the `build` method using `ref.watch` and the provider will rebuild correctly.